# Error on web hosting, bash: acme.sh: command not found

Tags: linux, ssl, server, openssl, hosting

I'm trying to install Let's Encrypt SSL on my server on Namecheap, need to [register an account first](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/zerossl.com-ca) and following this instruction on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVbGW037fYk&lc=Ugziq4e0fpETosnqDhZ4AaABAg.9YDyLlYqoyy9YMGcMI3Cvu). However, it kept showing  that command not found, why is this so?

[image: bash: acme.sh: command not found]

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after installing acme, you'll need to restart your shell session before you can use it.

```
OK, Close and reopen your terminal to start using acme.sh
```

https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/issues/1412